# Write to External File without ending the program

Tags: java, printwriter

I have a program that is only meant to be terminated by pressing `Ctrl + C`. In this program I write to an external file using:

```
File logFile = new File("output.txt");
PrintWriter log_file_writer = new PrintWriter(logFile);
log_file_writer.println("TEXT");
```

However because I don't know when the program will be terminated, I can't close the file using:

```
log_file_writer.close();
```

I think this is resulting in no text appearing in the output file.

Would anyone have a solution for this?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `flush` the `PrintWriter`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
log_file_writer.flush();
```

will push the content to disk

Answer (score 1):

As the [javadoc says](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter%28java.io.File%29):

> `PrintWriter(File file)` Creates a new PrintWriter, without automatic line flushing, with the specified file.

Therefore, you need to flush the data you want to print that is actually buffered:

```
log_file_writer.flush();
```

Comment: No problem. I hope it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You did not flush the content, I always use the `autoFlush` argument, but it is not available with `File`:

```
PrintWriter log_file_writer = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("output.txt"),true);
```

but you can also use `log_file_writer.flush();` after each write.

Comment: Thanks Djon. Yes, I'm just "flushing" after each write.